# Click on the button on website

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

do you lose the browsing of websites and I need using python click on the "Další holky prosím" at the bottom of the page http://www.lide.cz/ I tried to program something but it did not work. Please consult Thank you

```
with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
 browser.get('http://www.lide.cz/')

 options=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("span.button.zeny")
 for i in options:
     print('nasel')
     i.click()

 page_source = browser.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
 for i in soup.findAll('a'):``
     out=(i).get("href")
     if out.find('/detail/')!= -1:
        print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
options=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("span.button.zeny")
```

with

```
options=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="profiles"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To click "Další holky prosím" button, you can try this one:

```
options=browser.find_elements_by_class_name(".button") // css selector
```

Or this one:

```
options=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="button zeny"]') //xpath expression
```